# Converting DXF files to SHP format in C#

Tags: c#, shapefile, dxf

I must convert big DXF files to SHP format and after much research it seemed that there is no free software for this, but also I couldn't find any open source solutions for this problem.

I found several solutions which need CADImport.dll, but it's not free.
Also I found several solutions on Codeproject ([1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3398/CadLib-for-creating-DXF-Drawing-Interchange-Format), [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156522/DXF-Import-NET-Read-and-View-AutoCAD-Format-Files), [3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11570/A-DXF-Reader-Solution-and-a-Simple-DXF-Viewer)), but anyone worked fine.

How can I open DXF file in C# and get all polylines in it?

Comment: Ogr2Ogr tool can be used to convert between various vector formats. There is an answer in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348640/converting-dxf-to-esri-shapefile-using-ogr2ogr).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link. There is a sample project you can download.
http://www.weresc.com/cadeControl.php